# Javascript function true/false

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've got the below function that checks the return message from the server to see if its true/false, however it doesn't seem to be returning true or false.

```
// Return from server 
xhr.onload = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    Ti.API.info(data);
    if (data.success == true) {
        Ti.API.info('Logged In');
        return true;
        // If not flag an error 
    } else {
        return false;
        Ti.API.info('Failed Registration');
    };
};
```

This is the message this is returned from the server, where success will either be 0 or 1.

```
{
  message = "Username already exists.";
  success = 0;
}
```

Comment: `return false; Ti.API.info('Failed Registration');` - second instruction is unreachable.

Comment: And to whom shall it return a value? It's an event handler after all.

Answer (score 1):

Basically `if-else` cannot chose third path to follow, it will always be on of the two. With your code, however, I think the problem is with the instructions order, it should be:

```
// Return from server 
xhr.onload = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    Ti.API.info(data);
    if (data.success == true) {
        Ti.API.info('Logged In');
        return true;
        // If not flag an error 
    } else {
        Ti.API.info('Failed Registration');
        return false;
    };
};
```

So that either `Logged In` or `Failed Registration` will be called.
In your original post `success=0` was evaluated as `false`, but due to `return` statement being first one - `Ti.API.info('Failed Registration');` was never executed.